# Tires uneven measurements

Tags: honda, tires, civic, winter

So for winter tires, I have 16 inch in the front and 15inch in the back, both are winter tires, is this deadly? I know I should change this but the car I'm driving is gonna go after this winter, I'm getting a new one, so don't want to shell out 300$ on it.

Front tires: michelin siz:205/55/16
Rear tires: goodrich size:195/65/15

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission of the vehicle in question?

Comment: Honda civic 2006, automatic

Comment: Does your vehicle have anti-lock brakes? What are the exact *tire* sizes on the wheels? I'm looking for whatever the: P135/65R14 ... yadda-yadda-yadda is ... :D ... both tire sizes ... also what brand/model they are ... just edit your question and put ALL of this information in there.

Comment: I've added the details

Comment: You've added *some* details. The other details about your car are *very* important if you want a good answer to your question. Does your car have anit-lock brakes?

Comment: Yeah it does have anti lock brakes, sorry, didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [TireRack.com](http://www.tirerack.com/), your standard tire size is 195/65/15. This tire has a rotation per mile (RPM) of 832. The Michelin tire has an RPM of 836. This is only a difference of ~.5%, which is not a big deal. **Using the two different tire sizes shouldn't cause you any issues.**

The major concerns here is to keep the same size tires on the same axle (front or back). If you put different size tires on each side, it could cause instability issues.

The concern I had with anti-lock brakes (ABS) is if there is too much of a difference in sizes, it will drive the ABS and/or stability program crazy, shutting both down and making that function useless to you. This would, of course, cause a safety concern for you which I assume you were trying to avoid in the first place.